# Is it possible to use Google speech recognition in the Google Translate application for Android while offline?

Tags: voice-recognition, google-translate

Is it possible to use Google speech recognition in the Google Translate application for Android while offline?

When I try, it says that Google voice typing can't be used "in this field", and the built-in speech recognition in Google Translate doesn't work when offline.

Google voice typing does work in other applications when I'm offline, as I download the speech recognition model:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Google forums](https://support.google.com/translate/thread/15303993?msgid=15358513) as of September this year

> You cannot translate voice offline.