# Translating speech offline

Tags: voice-recognition, text-to-speech, translate

[Is it possible to use Google speech recognition in the Google Translate application for Android while offline?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219797/330250) clarified that Google Translate cannot translate voice offline. Are there any other possibilities to translate voice offline (e.g. abroad)?
I have already checked Google Translate, Bing Translate, Yandex Translate and DeepL. Maye a combination of Apps/Extensions can achieve this goal?

Comment: Duplicate of: [Android App to translate conversations offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/87431/2543). Do realize that existing open-source text translation models like [LibreTranslate](https://github.com/LibreTranslate/LibreTranslate) depend upon a hosted server and since [Android is not fully POSIX Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27604455/295004) some effort needs be made for full offline support on mobile device.